# what is the difference between create() and insert() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

What is the exact difference between `create()` and `insert()` in Laravel? I have gone through videos and blogs but didn't find any satisfying answers.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075639/whats-difference-between-laravel-model-functions-create-and-insert?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

`create()` is a function from Eloquent, `insert()` - Query Builder.

`create()` - [API doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_create)

`insert()` - [API doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insert)

In other words, create is just an Eloquent model function that handles the creation of the object to the DB (in a more abstract way). Insert however tries to create the actual query string. Would not be surprised to see `insert()` somewhere under the hood of `create()` - but haven't checked.